# Image path URL not Rending right in google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, iframe

[image]I am trying to build an web app using apps script it was working well till yesterday but I don't know why my password recovery pages not rendering right. the image URL path getting mess, including googlescriptappconsle link automatically.

**I am getting this error:**

- [image: Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://script.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://n-hkpdnu3lqaw4tsnsfwzli6eib5wsy4yfjucqesi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation must be same-origin with the target if navigating to a javascript: url]

I tried to debug and checked the script a lot but not found any error in that. don't know why this msg is showing and how to fix this.

forget Password? link at login.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="recoveryScreen()">Forget Password</a>
```

JavaScript.

```js
function recoveryScreen() {
  return document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = `
         <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
             <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/authentication-concept-illustration_114360-1640.jpg?t=st=1650012022~exp=1650012622~hmac=0b7d5c7400d49f971b6c626c09516602556c052642171457305bfaf5c17e2461&w=740" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>   
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                 <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-item-center recoveryInput">
                     <p class="text-center hide">For update your password please provide your email address here.</p>
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" class="hide">
                     <button type="button" onclick="sendRecoveryLink()" class="hide">Get OTP</button>
                     <button type="button" onclick="showLogin()" class="mt-2 hide" style="background-color:black;">Back</button>
                     <p class="pt-4 text-center show" id="msgpara" style="color:red; display: none;">We have sent you an OTP on your mail for update password.</p>
                     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter OTP" id="otp" class="show" style="display: none;">
                     <input type="text" placeholder="New Password" id="newpswd" class="show" style="display: none;">
                     <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirmpswd" class="show" style="display: none;">
                     <button type="button" id="update" class="show" style="display: none;">Update</button>
                 </div>  
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>`
}
```

HTML.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: When I tested your HTML and Javascript with Web Apps, dialog and sidebar, I confirmed that your image can be seen. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for this. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? Or, for example, when you create a new Google Apps Script project and copy and paste your script and test it, the same issue occurs again?

Comment: @tanaike hey thanks for the comment, I am on the way to try this now i am deploying whole project with other Gmail account to check where it's showing error or not..in short summary ..issue is that when someone click on forget password someone its including script URL with images URL see in screenshot that's why image is not showing but I don't know why this happening I use preventDefault() method too but no luck.

Comment: @tanaike I check to deploy still the same issue

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand your issue and replicate it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @tanaike thanks for struggle with me buddy. and okay if I say in short way then just look at the my first screenshot where you can see html structure there just see in the img src="" path the URL is not correct one and also html structure is messy.. this is issue because <a href=""> tag has default refresh or submit nature right? which i used for forget password link but put JavaScript void to avoid so its including that refresh path into img src URL instead of correct img URL that's why its not rendering and i don't know why this happening. Hope this helped you to understand

Comment: I'm with @Tanaike on this one - the example you provided definitely seems to be working. Makes me think that it's something else on your page which may be causing a quote mismatch here. Can you inspect the page and search for your `recoveryScreen()` function to see if the string there has been edited?

Comment: @i hope this is helpful to you - thanks for the comment i don't know what happening this issue arriving only when i trying to deploy my code on google apps script otherwise everything is working perfectly on local server in vs code and there is no update and changes I did its just starting happen out of blue...

Comment: Were you able to view your `recoveryScreen()` function from the source?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou not at all, don't know why when i am deploying this on Apps script. it's not rendering but working fine at local PC server. and in VS Code.. other final stuff are pending once this web app complete i will try to deploy whole code with other gmail account let see if that works other wise... it won't be fix i guess

Comment: Have you tried to insert the HTML on Apps Script side by creating a template and evaluating it? Might be a way to solve this

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou the project is complete and I also deployed with another google account but same issue happening and about your suggestion. I did not try that solution yet... you saying using HTML  code instead of render this with JavaScript dynamically...Right?

Comment: Exactly - use `<?!= scriptlets ?>` to insert the html on Apps Script side and then evaluate the HTML page template rather than creating the HTML output and inserting it in the page on load

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou I have tried but did not worked. can you show the example ?